# Adding data to a XML data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table that contains a xml data type which acts like an audit log.

```
CREATE TABLE T (i int, log xml);
```

Where the log structure is something like:

```
<auditLog>
<entry action="Created" description="New item created" value="banana" />
<entry action="Deleted" description="Deleted item" value="apple" />
</auditLog>
```

I am trying to figure out if/how it is possible to add another entry to this xml file. I have found lots of functions to add nodes to the current entries but not how to make a new entry. I assume that there must be a simple way of doing this but I cant seem to find it.

Any pointers would be very welcome.

Comment: Do you want to add a new row in the table or a new <entry> node inside <auditlog>?

Comment: You **are** adding a node to the current entry of `<auditLog>`, so those functions should work for you. If they don't please post your attempt :)

Comment: Did you try `FOR XML`?

Comment: Ah, so would it be just a matter of adding a node inside <auditLog>  which contains all of the information that is in the entry node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably confused by the fact that your XML node's name is `entry`. What you are doing is inserting a new node into your XML data. You can use this:

```
UPDATE T
    SET [log].modify('
    insert <entry action="Added" description="New entry added" value="orange" />
    as last
    into (/auditLog)[1]')
    WHERE i = 1
```

More documentation and examples: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms175466.aspx)

Comment: Yes of course. I was getting rather confused and didn't realize that I could simply add a node to <auditLog> to effectively add an 'entry'.